# How to adjust picture geometry of a CRT TV?

Tags: monitor, tv, crt

I have a HD CRT TV (Silva Schneider 26 inch) which failed recently. So I took apart a working CRT TV (Philips L01-2E AA, 20 inch) and took its mainboard and connected it properly to the HD CRT tube.
The tube lights up, it works, but the picture is small.
[image: HD CRT tube with Philips mainboard]

How can I enlarge the picture? There are no pots for horizontal and vertical adjustments on the mainboard, also the service menu is currently not available, because of missing remote control.

Comment: How do you expect the deflection driver circuits to work on a different size tube from a different manufacturer?

Comment: As far as I know, the CRT TV tubes are analog devices with no fixed resolution, all of them work similarly, except in this case the HD CRT tube is bigger, so perhaps the voltage which drives the tube's deflection coils needs to be higher. If this is the case, how can this be achieved on the mainboard?

Comment: Now that you know the tube and deflection coils are OK, you can fix the original mainboard!

Comment: Thanks Bruce. The original mainboard has a problem, it wont start up, it just cycles. Perhaps the B+ voltage is low. The original mainboard cannot achieve high voltage in the tube, also the filaments don't light up, no sound.

Comment: You would have to increase the deflection amplitudes. It would most likely involve increasing the supply voltage to the board, which would most likely destroy it before you achieved your goal. Fixing the original one is a better bet.

Comment: Thanks Brian. I could transform the horizontal and vertical amplitudes with a hand wound coil transformer, right at the H and V output on the board. Actually with two of them - one for H, one for V. Could this word theoretically? As I see from the picture, the deflection voltages should be boosted 4 times, this means 1:4 ratio.

Comment: Correction: I meant toroidal transformers.

Comment: That picture is so very small that you're just not going to get there from here -- if things were off by 10% or so you could maybe adjust them, but you're looking at trying to rewind the deflection coils.  Fixing the electronics that go with the TV will be easier.

Comment: Thanks TimWescott. I will try transforming the horizontal and vertical output signals by 4 to the tube, I guess the board has back EMF protection already, so I wont fry it.

Comment: I tried transforming the sync signals to the deflection coils and overloaded the circuitry. Perhaps next time an active amplification will be necessary. Thanks for all the comments.

Answer (score 1):

The only option is to get a universal remote control. It should have a tiny hole just below the 'channel down' down button which you press with a pointed device like a DMM probe to access the factory settings. If it brings up the menu, you should see options for vertical and horizontal size, positioning etc. Good luck.

Comment: This is not going to work in the case shown in the question above. They have a problem with the deflection board--with the hardware, not with the settings.